# How to execute some code in parallel while in a loop that should continue?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key,api_secret)
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ms = bm.multiplex_socket(multi)
    # connects to broker and starts a websockets stream of prices
    async with ms as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            if res:

#this part is what I need
#run_a_trade_function in parallel while allowing this main loop to continue
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: It really depends on what your needs are. If your code spends its time waiting on I/O, asyncio is a great choice provided you have asyncio-aware code available to conduct the I/O. If not, threads are a better choice. If your code spends its time waiting for CPU-bound operations, you'll want processes instead. concurrent.futures will help you with the non-asyncio options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two pieces of code to run at the same time you'll need to use some variant of multi-threading. Python has a built in library for this [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Multi-threading is a very powerful tool but introduces a lot of potential bugs so perhaps look for a different approach first.

Comment: I was thinking more in the direction of Multiprocessing

Comment: TIL those two are different things, fortunately Python has a library for that too
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html